# General function applied to tagged types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have defined these types:

```
data Km     = Km Float deriving (Show, Eq)
data Mile   = Mile Float deriving (Show, Eq)
data Meter  = Meter Float deriving (Show, Eq)
data Feet   = Feet Float deriving (Show, Eq)
```

And I have some functions like:

```
kms_to_miles    :: Km   -> Meter
kms_to_feets    :: Km   -> Feet
miles_to_meters :: Mile -> Meter
```

This is perfect because I can't mix units.

Now, if I have some simple function:

```
doubleTheDistance' :: Float -> Float
doubleTheDistance' x = 2 * x
```

And I want to apply it to my types I could:

```
class Dbl a where
    doubleTheDistance :: a -> a
instance Dbl Km where
    doubleTheDistance (Km x) = Km (2 * x)
instance Dbl Mile where
    doubleTheDistance (Mile x) = Mile (2 * x)
--  an instance with the same for all my types here...
```

As my types are not parametric, I can't use a Functor and map a general function (*doubleTheDistance'*) over them.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to abstract this behaviour so I don't have to write the same function for every tagged type?

Comment: You can use a Unit data type, declare newtypes wrapping it, and use generalized newtype deriving extension to avoid redefining the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to use [phantom type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type) to encode "units". Which still gives you type-safe specific types, like `Distance Km`, but also allows you to apply more generic functions, like `doubleTheDistance`, when needed:

```
data Km
data Mile
data Meter
data Feet

data Distance m = Distance Float  deriving (Show, Eq)

kms_to_miles :: Distance Km -> Distance Mile
kms_to_miles (Distance km) = Distance (km*0.621371192)

doubleTheDistance :: Distance m -> Distance m
doubleTheDistance (Distance x) = Distance (2 * x)

-- Tests
km = Distance 5 :: Distance Km

doubled = doubleTheDistance km
```

You can even `show` it nicely your `Distance`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}

data Km
data Mile
data Meter
data Feet

data Distance m = Distance Float deriving Eq

instance Show Km where
   show _ = "km"
instance Show Mile where
   show _ = "ml"
instance Show Feet where
   show _ = "ft"

instance Show m => Show (Distance m) where
   show (Distance a) = show a ++ " " ++ show (undefined :: m)

km = Distance 5 :: Distance Km -- Is shown as "0.5 km"
```

Comment: This is perfect (and with a Show bonus!). My first contact with phantom types. For all the beginners like myself out there: "{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}" activate a Haskell extension that is necessary to make "show (undefined :: m)" to work. See:        http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables

Answer (score 4):

As usual, `lens` can simplify this a whole lot. It provides a facility for converting from and to newtypes via `Iso`s.

Add an instance of your newtypes to the [`Wrapped`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html) class:

```
newtype Km = Km { getFloatKm :: Float }
makeWrapped ''Km
```

Now you can use the normal `Iso` facilities to work with your newtype wrapper. You can get at the `Iso` via the `_Unwrapped` and `_Wrapped` functions:

```
let x = Km 5 in x & _Wrapped %~ (*2)
> Km {getFloatKm = 10.0}
```

This is of course more generally powerful than this simple example.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`Control.Lens.TH.makeWrapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeWrapped).

Answer (score 1):

One approach without extensions:

```
class Distance a where
  toFloat :: a -> Float
  fromFloat :: Float -> a

instance Distance Miles where
  toFloat (Miles x) = x
  fromFloat x = Miles x

-- same for other units

mapDistance :: Distance a => (Float -> Float) -> a -> a
mapDistance f = fromFloat . f . toFloat

doubleTheDistance = mapDistance (* 2.0)
```

You still need some duplication, but it's once per unit, not once per function. In practice I'd most likely prefer Simon's approach. Of course, they can be combined:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

instance Distance Float where
  toFloat x = x
  fromFloat x = x

newType Km = Km Float deriving (Show, Eq, Distance)

-- definitions of mapDistance and doubleTheDistance as above
```

Comment: I will go with newtype and record syntax "Km (doubleTheDistance' (kms a))". Yet, I find strange that Haskell don't let you make pattern matching against the type in a tagged type: any type discrepancy should be visible in compiling time.